# Merging PDFs by code

Tags: java, vba, pdf, automation, adobe

What I want is:

I have PDF document in english and an other languages and always pairs with the same content. I want to merge exactly the pairs, but I got tons of them (but the pairs have quiet similiar names), so I don't want to do it manually.

What I do have:

some experience with Java and VBA and yet installed Microsoft Office Suite XP and Adobe Acrobat Professional 8. Any other software has to be for free... if needed.

Can you help me to find a solution. Anything would help I only found solutions for newer versions of Excel and Acrobat Professional on the web.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished using [IText](http://itextpdf.com/), which is an open source package that processes Pdfs. There are Java and C# versions.

Here is some example java code that I wrote to merge several pdfs

```
/**
 * merge multiple pdfs into a single pdf
 * @param fileName output pdf full path name
 * @parrm childPdfs full path names of pdfs to merge
 */
public static void mergePdfs(String fileName, String [] childPdfs) {
try {

    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfCopy copyDoc =  new PdfCopy(doc, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    doc.open();
    for (int i = 0; i < childPdfs.length; i++) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(childPdfs [i]);
        int pageCnt = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int j = 1; j <= pageCnt; j++) {
            copyDoc.addPage(copyDoc.getImportedPage(reader, j));
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    doc.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw  new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```